# ERC1155 per token variables

Tags: solidity, erc-721, erc-1155, nft

I want to create an NFT that can mint different character types and multiple clones of each type. The clones within each type will start with same metadata, but each individual token should have its own XP value which can change over time.
This variable needs to be able to be displayed on platforms such as opensea.

Should I create a mapping of token id to XP value in the ERC1155 contract, then get my metadata API to read the current XP value from the blockchain?
Or are there examples to implement this more efficiently?